# Transforming game tree to the list of players' behavior

Tags: c#, algorithm

Consider a game in which `N` players compete for some prize

players are numbered `1` to `N`, have `A1...AN` amounts of money and make moves in a circle

player `1` is the first to act

he can either bet amount `a1<=A1` or pass the turn to player `2`

if player `1` bets, then player `2` can put a bigger bet a2>a1, given that `a2<=A2`, or pass

the next player can put a bigger bet `a3>a2`, given that `a3<=A3`, or pass and so son

if the move returns to player `1`, he can add money to his bet so that `(a1+added money)>ai` where `ai` is the last bet made, given that `a1+added money<=A1`

each player is limited to `2` actions per game

The game description consists of

- the player list where each item contains the `player ID`, his position(`1...N`), and his initial amount of money
- the ordered action list where each item contains the `player ID`, the `action`(bet/pass), and the `amount` of the bet if any

Example:

Player List:

| PlayerId | Position | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 1 | 60 |
| P2 | 2 | 140 |
| P3 | 3 | 90 |
| P4 | 4 | 200 |

Action List:

| PlayerId | Action | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | bet | 20 |
| P2 | pass |  |
| P3 | raise | 30 |
| P4 | raise | 40 |
| P1 | raise | 60 |
| P3 | pass |  |
| P4 | pass |  |

Given the game description as the input, I want to transform it to the
list of N items where each item describes the player's behavior in the game:

- PlayerId,
- Could Bet First(true if a player had the opportunity to start betting, false otherwise),
- Bet First (true if a player started betting, false otherwise)
- Could Raise(true if a player had the opportunity to raise the previous bet, false otherwise),
- Raised(true if a player had the opportunity to raise the previous bet, false otherwise),
- Could Re-raise(true if a player had the opportunity to re-raise, false otherwise),
- Re-raised(true if a player bet first, was raised, and re-raised, false otherwise),
- Number of times player was active(bet, raised, or reraised)
- The total amount of money the player put in the game

The output for the aforementioned example should be:

- P1, True, True, False, False, True, True, 2, 60
- P2, False, False, False, False, False, False, 0, 0
- P3, False, False, True, True, True, False, 1, 30
- P4, False, False, True, True, True, False, 1, 40

Ideally, the code would go through the list of actions once and build the desired outcome by updating the player's stat objects with each action. Can anyone suggest an algorithm for solving this problem?

Comment: MCTS (monte carlo tree search). or, a little bit simpler to start with, just a basic depth search on the game tree

Comment: @draz the OP is not looking to make a game AI, they're asking how to aggregate the list of actions over the whole game to a list of stats per player

Comment: hmm, if you already have collected the players behaviour and there is no need to calculate it, I actually do not see the problem of retrieving the information (?)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, define a class that matches the desired output data:

```
class PlayerStatistics
{
    public string PlayerId { get; set; }
    public bool CouldBetFirst { get; set; }
    public bool BetFirst { get; set; }
    public bool CouldRaise { get; set; }
    public bool Raised { get; set; }
    public bool CouldReraise { get; set; }
    public bool Reraised { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfActions { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPlaced { get; set; }
}
```

You know how many players there are, and you know there will be one of these statistics objects per player, so you can make a list or array of them.

Now comes the aggregation. You have the list of actions that were taken, but you are also concerned with actions that were *possible* for your statistics. This means you have to replay the game and keep track of the game state somewhere, so you know if the player actually had enough money remaining to bet, raise etc.

```
class PlayerState
{
    public string PlayerId { get; set; }
    public bool Passed { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountAvailable { get; set; }
    public decimal AmountPlaced { get; set; }
}

// These variables make up the game state
decimal highestAmountPlaced = 0;
int leadingPlayerIndex = -1;
var playerStates = new PlayerState[players.Count];

// Initialize the player states using the info in the list of players
for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < players.Count; playerIndex++)
{
    playerStates[playerIndex].PlayerId = players[playerIndex].PlayerId;
    playerStates[playerIndex].AmountAvailable = players[playerIndex].Amount;
}
```

Each player can only perform two actions. That means you can simply loop through the list of players 2 times. The loop might exit early if someone wins before then. The key point here is to keep track of the current action, in a variable with a larger scope than the loops, so we can replay the actions in each loop.

```
int actionIndex = 0;

for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < players.Count; playerIndex++)
{
    var playerState = states[playerIndex];
    if (leadingPlayerIndex == -1)
    {
        playerState.CouldBetFirst = true;
    }
    else if (playerState.Available > amountPlaced)
    {
        playerState.CouldRaise = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // They can't raise, but can they match, can they go all-in?
    }

    var playerAction = actions[actionIndex];
    var playerStatistics = statistics[playerIndex];
    switch (playerAction.Action)
    {
        case "bet":
            playerStatistics.BetFirst = true;
            playerStatistics.NumberOfActions++;
            playerState.AmountPlaced += playerAction.Amount;
            playerState.AmountAvailable -= playerAction.Amount;
            highestAmountPlaced = playerState.AmountPlaced;
            leadingPlayerIndex = playerIndex;
            break;
        case "raise":
            playerStatistics.Raised = true;
            playerStatistics.NumberOfActions++;
            playerState.AmountPlaced += playerAction.Amount;
            playerState.AmountAvailable -= playerAction.Amount;
            highestAmountPlaced = playerState.AmountPlaced;
            leadingPlayerIndex = playerIndex;
            break;
        case "pass":
            playerState.Passed = true;
            break;
    }

    actionIndex++;
}

if (actionIndex < actions.Count)
{
    for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < players.Count; playerIndex++)
    {
        var playerState = states[playerIndex];
        if (playerState.Passed)
            continue;

        if (leadingPlayerIndex == playerIndex)
        {
            // This player is still leading the bet
            break;
        }
        else if (playerState.Available > amountPlaced)
        {
            playerState.CouldReraise = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // They can't raise, but can they match, can they go all-in?
        }

        var playerAction = actions[actionIndex];
        var playerStatistics = statistics[playerIndex];
        switch (playerAction.Action)
        {
            case "raise":
                playerStatistics.Reraised = true;
                playerStatistics.NumberOfActions++;
                playerState.AmountPlaced += playerAction.Amount;
                playerState.AmountAvailable -= playerAction.Amount;
                highestAmountPlaced = playerState.AmountPlaced;
                leadingPlayerIndex = playerIndex;
                break;
            case "pass":
                playerState.Passed = true;
                break;
        }

        actionIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to solve all 9 "problems". an acceptance for doing the work would probably be appropriate...